# Making a OneWayToSource/TwoWay binding on custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, custom-controls

I have a custom control with a dependency property, defines as follows:

```
public class TemplatedTextBox : TextBox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SearchStringProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SearchString", typeof(string), typeof(TemplatedTextBox), new UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public string SearchString
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(SearchStringProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SearchStringProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

I use the following control template:

```
    <WpfApp:TemplatedTextBox>
        <WpfApp:TemplatedTextBox.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type WpfApp:TemplatedTextBox}">
                <StackPanel Height="20" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Search String :"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="SearchTextBox"  Width="200" Text="NEED TO BE BINDED TO SearchString!"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </WpfApp:TemplatedTextBox.Template>
    </WpfApp:TemplatedTextBox>
```

I want to bind `SearchTextBox`'s `Text` property to my `SearchString` property in a `OneWayToSource` or `TwoWay` binding mode.

I've tried:

```
Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=SearchString, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
```

Which doesn't do nothing.

```
Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=SearchString, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

And

```
Text="{TemplateBinding SearchString}"
```

Which works fine in one direction when I programatically change `SearchString` the `Text` on `TextBox` changes, but not the other way

I've also tried making `SearchString` a regular property and bind it using `RelativeSource` in all sorts of `Mode`s but it didn't work.

This is a pretty straight forward thing to do in regular View-to-ViewModel binding, so what am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried it and it works as expected.
Could it be something simply, e.g. you are not leaving the textbox after entering the characters so the binding does not trigger ?

Try to add `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`, to trigger the binding on each character entered.

Comment: I can't believe I keep failing on stupid stuff like `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` ... Thanks you!

Comment: @Omribitan Everyone does that. It always annoys me that textbox doesn't have propertychanged as default, it makes sense for validation.